# Can you create clickable labels or text using monogame C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monogame

The title says most of it. I'm specifically having a problem with creating labels in a monogame mobile game. I'm operating inside vs2022. It is the android project.

I can create the label:

```
Label label = new Label();
```

However, when trying to give it text:

```
label.Text = "Start Game";
```

I get an error saying label does not contain a definition for Text.

I feel like it has something to do with not being able to include the library:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

It says Forms does not exist in the namespace System.Windows

Which, I know it does when in the regular C# vs environment, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I've tried searching for labels in monogame, but there aren't any hits coming back that I could find.
I've also tried linklabel:

```
LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
linkLabel.Text = "Start Game";
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `Xamarin.Android` a label is called a `TextView`, And the reason it says System.Windows.Forms doesn't exist is because it does not exist in XAMARIN ANDROID....

Comment: `Which, I know it does when in the regular C# vs environment, so I'm not sure what the issue is.` This is not your regular C# VS environment its Xamarin ALOT IS DIFFERENT

Comment: Thank you for that information. Are they clickable?

Comment: Yes they are, you might want to take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/

Comment: Hi, I'm going through the documentation now. I appreciate that.
I edited my post to reflect my current issue. If you could provide any new insight, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Wait, I'm making some progress passing: Android.App.Application.Context instead of this.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Android? Because on Android All activities and Fragments have their context

Comment: Do you want your link within the game (in Monogame)? Because then you should not work with either `Label` or `LinkLabel`, since these are Xamarin/Windows.Forms elements that you should not be using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but not in the way you expect; forms and events go out the window when using Monogame.

Windows.Forms is not used under Monogame for Android Apps.

Create an object(class) that draws the text and checks for touch input on the object.